# Check if text contains URL

Tags: php

How can I check if text in PHP contains a link in it's text?
I have a database table format as follow.

```
+------------------+
| id | posts | tag |
+------------------+
| 1  | text 1|  0  | //no links
| 2  | text 2|  1  | //contains links
```

Basically, I want to verify that the submitted entry contains a link, if it does, 
the `tag` column will have a value of `1`.

Can someone help me to properly code the above sample? Currently this is my PHP:

```
include 'function.php';

$text= $_POST['text'];

//if $text contains a url then do this function 
postEntryWithUrl($text);

//else here 
postEntry($text);
```

Comment: You can use Regular expression based search, look for URL regex on google.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: If you ask about a string, ask a bout a string, not write long sentences about some database first. Keep Q&A to the concrete question, it's not here your support forum. Also take a look where this question has been asked before and answered. Then outline why the existing answers you have tried so far didn't make it to you. Until then I suggest to close to keep this site more straight to the point.

Comment: sorry for that, i promise to keep that in mind. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stristr()`

```
$has_link = stristr($string, 'http://') ?: stristr($string, 'https://');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Or `preg_match()`

```
preg_match('/(http|ftp|mailto)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: What if there is no 'http://' but only 'www.' or neither?

Comment: Reason for the down vote?

Comment: I truthfully didn't notice I did that. Apologies.

Comment: @OraBrush no worries. Mine was just a guess, given the lack of context from the OP. Although he mentioned `$text contains a url`, I assume it's a fully qualified one. Certainly my answer doesn't work with SSL URL's though.

Comment: $has_link = (stristr($string, 'http')||stristr($string, 'www.'));  //is a more clinical solution, it matches both http, https and www. It's also case insensitive.

Comment: what if i wrote only "google.com" ?

Comment: This answer covers only 1 URL scheme, What if there's https infront or nothing like @rushil said. This answer should not be checked as answer...

Comment: Due to popular demand I've  updated my answer, hoping it could help. @strix25 `href="google.com"` will be treated as a local path, e.g. `http://example.com/google.com`, it won't point to Google.

Answer (score 13):

```
$text = (string) $_POST['text'];

$bHasLink = strpos($text, 'http') !== false || strpos($text, 'www.') !== false;

if($bHasLink){
    postEntryWithUrl($text);
}else{
    postEntry($text);
}
```