# Laravel allow links on message

Tags: laravel, chat

I need allow links in messages, when user send message. How I can do this?

```
@foreach($mess as $message)
              <li data-mid="{{ $message->id }}">
                  <div class="row margin-left-none margin-right-none">
                      <div class="col-md-2 padding-right-none">
                          <div class="avatar-user text-center">
                                  <img src="{{ $message->sender->avatar }}" alt="$message->sender->name">
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-10 padding-left-none">
                          <div class="user-name">
                              <span>{{ $message->sender->name }}
                                  @if(Helper::getOnlineUser($message->sender->id))
                                  <i data-toggle="tooltip" title="Онлайн" class="material-icons online">fiber_manual_record</i>
                                  @else 
                                  <i data-toggle="tooltip" title="Оффлайн" class="material-icons offline">fiber_manual_record</i>
                                  @endif
                                  <span class="date float-right">{{ $message->created_at->formatLocalized('%H:%m') }}</span></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="message">
                              {{ $message->body }}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
              @endforeach
```

This is view of messages.

How I can allow links?

Example: http://example.com in messages =>

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

I need {!! $message->body !!} ? Or How?

In controller:

```
$mess = Chat::conversations($conversation)->for($user)->getMessages($limit, $request->page);
```

I use this package: https://github.com/musonza/chat

Comment: You need to identify the send message consist of link or not ?

Comment: Yes. I need check if in message link: http://example.com, that transform this link on <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> and send user, so that he can click on this link.

Comment: May be this question help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463929/check-if-text-contains-url

Comment: no this don't help me, I need with laravel check this

Comment: I've added my answer right now, please have a try and feel free to ask if any problem :D

Comment: Did you got solution ?
congrats any way :D

Comment: No. Your answer fix solutions it's work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built in PHP functions to handle this:

```
<div class="message">
     {!! strip_tags($message->body, '<a>') !!}
</div>
```

Where the second argument is your whitelist.

This has the following advantages:

- You're not messing with regex
- You're still using blade `{!!!!}`
- You're using well tested code dev'ed by the core team

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using following php function in your blade,

```
<?php
    function getDataWithURL($text){
        // The Regular Expression filter
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

        // Check if there is a url in the text
        if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
               // make the urls hyper links
               echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=".$url[0].">".$url[0]."</a> ", $text);

        } else {
               // if no urls in the text just return the text
               echo $text;

        }
    }
?>
```

You just need to add this code in your blade file and then you can check and replace the links in your text like this,

```
<div class="message">
     <?php getDataWithURL($message->body);?>
</div>
```

I hope you will understand.