# How to prevent form submission if message contain links?

Tags: php, forms, contacts, spam

can anyone help me? I'm trying to prevent spam in the contact form.
I would like to achieve this with PHP. I can't find any solution on the web. Thanks in advance for who can help me out.

---

**HTML**

```
   <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="contact-form.php">   
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control mt-3" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control mt-3" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>   
                        <textarea class="form-control mt-3" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type your message" rows="7" required></textarea>  
                        <input type="text" id="Nomoboto" name="Nomoboto"  value="800 800 1000" autocomplete="off"  />
                        <input type="text" id="PostItBoto" name="PostItBoto" value="93940" autocomplete="off"  />
                        <input type="text" id="Empty_Me" name="Empty_Me" value=""/>
                        <input type="text" id="Empty_You" name="Empty_You" value=""/>                  
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-3">Send Message</button>
                </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST ['name'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];
    $Empty_Me = $_POST ['Empty_Me'];
    $Empty_You = $_POST ['Empty_You'];
    
    $email_from = 'Contact Form';
    $email_subject = "New Form Submission";
    $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n". 
                  "User Email: $email.\n". 
                  "User Message: $message.\n".
                  "Empty_Me: $Empty_Me.\n".
                  "Empty_You: $Empty_You.\n";
    
    function email_validation($str) {
    return (!preg_match(
    "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$^", $str))
    ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
    
    
    $to = "info@mail.com";
    $headers = "From $email_from \r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
```

Comment: Your PHP code is not showing, can you please edit your question to include it?

Comment: Hi Andrea, the PHP code is below the HTML code

Comment: You can apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19463962/1529324) to `$email_body`

Comment: Thanks, Andrea, but I did not resolve my issue. My goal is to don't allow the user to add links to the message. If the user add a link, the form can't be submitted.